# Options_for_select with all groups except the current param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of groups by user in my `@userGroups` which I use in a `select_tag` with `options_for_select`. It works like a charm; But when I'm on page `groups/4/` I would like to show the selectbox excluding group 4 from the select box.

Any idea how to do so?

```
    <%= select_tag(:group_id, 
                    options_for_select(
                            @userGroups.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }
                    ), 
                    :prompt => "Choose group",
                    :id => "moveClientsToGroup") %>
```

Made a small test as such:

```
<% @a = current_user.groups.where("id <> ?", params[:id]) %>
<% @a.each do |f| %>
    <%= f.name %>
<% end %>
```

Which throws: `SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "groupusers" ON "groups"."id" = "groupusers"."group_id" WHERE "groupusers"."user_id" = ? AND (id != '4')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your index action inside your controller, you have the parameter. So when you populate the list `userGroups`, a condition can be made like this:

```
if params[:id]
  @userGroups = UserGroup.where("id <> ?", params[:id])
else
  @userGroups = UserGroup.all
end
```

P.S.: I don't know if the model name is UserGroup, i was just guessing, this is an example, so you can get the idea.

Comment: Yes, thanks. One thing, though; I use the variable in my whole application. Is it wiser to create a new variable for this case?

Comment: Oh p.s @userGroups is nothing more than `current_user.groups` ;)

Comment: You can put it inside `application_controller`, so it would be available application-wise.

Comment: I don't think you need another variable. I would recommend that only if somewhere in your app you need the two lists. One with the id and the other without it.

Comment: I made a little test(See my editted question) But it gives me an error `SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "groupusers" ON "groups"."id" = "groupusers"."group_id" WHERE "groupusers"."user_id" = ? AND (id != '4')`

Comment: Ah fixed it... Should be `group_id` instead of `id`. Your answer is correct!